# How to use the range function in java

Tags: java, range

I need help writing a program that will accept a number between a range from 0 to 9 and if the user enters a number in range I will print the number itself as many times as the number. Example: If the user enters 5 the output from the program will be "55555". Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Numbers{
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int oneDigit = 0;   

        try{
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter a number between 0 and 9: ");
            oneDigit = reader.nextInt(); 

            if (oneDigit < 0 || oneDigit > 9)
                System.out.println("You did not enter a number between 0 and 9!");
            else 

        }
        catch(InputMismatchException ime){
            System.out.println("You didn't enter a number.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is your else block empty?

Answer (score 2):

You need a `for` loop in the `else` to print the `oneDigit` as many no. of times.

```
else{
    for (int i = 0; i < oneDigit; i++) {
        System.out.print(oneDigit);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to skip the if condition itself you can use something like this

```
        for (int i = 0; i<num && num<=9 ; i++){
          System.out.print(num);
        }
```

but still you have to use an if condition to display an alert if the number is outside range